# Can I short power button always on?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an aging home server, Asus AT3IONT-I Deluxe, and I want it to power on automatically after a power loss. I have enabled the BIOS setting to do this but it doesn’t work. The power LED turns on but that’s all, it doesn’t actually boot.
[image]
Since this machine runs 24/7 would there by any harm in soldering the power button so it’s always shorted on?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I could easily answer my own question. With the power button shorted, the machine does power on automatically, but it shuts itself off after about 5 seconds. So that won’t work. Welp